# Set a character variable with an if - then statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am trying to set a variable, typeofauction, as either 'a' or 'f' with an if then statement.
dim typeofauction as char

```
typeofauction = typeofauction1.Text
    If (typeofauction = "Auction") Then
        listingtype = 'a'
    End If
    If (typeofauction = "Fixed Price") Then
        listingtype = 'f'
    End If
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you not debug and see whats happening, post the variable declaration and value that you are passing. make sure you don't have trailing space in your input and handle case comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you are trying to set `typeofauction`, which is defined as a `char` type, to 'a' or 'f'. However, your code shows you are trying to set `listingtype` which appears to be a `char`.

I think you have your types confused. Try:

```
Dim listingtype As Char

Dim typeofauction As String = typeofauction1.Text ' assuming this is a textbox

If typeofauction = "Auction" Then
   listingtype = "a"c
ElseIf typeofauction = "Fixed Price" Then
   listingtype = "f"c
End If
```

You don't *have* to use the `Char` type for `listingtype`. You can also use a `String` which will simply hold only one character.

Comment: Ah. I understand. thank you very much. And i have listingtype declared as a shared variable outside of the button which is why it was not included.

Answer (score 0):

You just declared `typeofauction as char`, so it just accepts one character.

You need to declare it as follows:

```
Dim typeofauction as String
```

Because "Auction" and "FixedPrices" are Strings.